# Unable to store video in documents directory

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

when i NSLog BOOL success = [videoDataDecrypted writeToFile:videopath atomically:NO];
this statement it always diplays No

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info {

NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
picker.allowsEditing = NO;
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

// Handle a movie capture
if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge_retained CFStringRef)mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0)
    == kCFCompareEqualTo) 
{

    NSString *moviePath = [[info objectForKey:
                            UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
    NSURL *movieURL1 = [NSURL URLWithString:moviePath];
    NSLog(@"moviePath %@",moviePath);

    NSData *videoDataEncrypted = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:movieURL1];
    [videoDataEncrypted AES256EncryptWithKey:@"123"];

    NSData *videoDataDecrypted = [videoDataDecrypted AES256DecryptWithKey:@"123"];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:SS"];
    NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];

    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Default Album"];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath 
                                  withIntermediateDirectories:NO 
                                                   attributes:nil
                                                        error:nil];

    NSString *videopath= [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString
                               stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.mov",documentsDirectory,theDate]];

    BOOL success = [videoDataDecrypted writeToFile:videopath atomically:NO];

    NSLog(@"Successs:::: %@", success ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    NSLog(@"video path --> %@",videopath);

    NSString* urlTextEscaped = [videopath 
                         stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSURL *movieUrl2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlTextEscaped];


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1,1));

    MPMoviePlayerViewController* theMovie =
    [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL: movieUrl2];

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:theMovie];

    // Register for the playback finished notification
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver: self
     selector: @selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:)
     name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object: theMovie];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for store video,

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Default Album"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
      [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];

    NSString *videopath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.mov",dataPath,theDate];
    [videoDataDecrypted writeToFile:videopath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: In above case i am unable to store video

Answer (score 0):

try this way...

```
#define DOCUMENTS_FOLDER [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]

//Open Camera

           if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
                 UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
            {
         UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
                
                imagePicker.delegate = self;
                imagePicker.sourceType =UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                
                imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeMovie,nil];
                imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
              
                [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark - ImagePicker Controller Delegate
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:true];
    
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
       NSString *f_name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/video1.mp4",DOCUMENTS_FOLDER];
        
        NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        
      //  self.movieURL=info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
        //NSString* imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
        ////NSLog(@"image path-%@",imagePath);
        
        [videoData writeToFile:f_name atomically:YES];
}
```